# Difficulty Returning A Dictionary From NSURL Session

Tags: return, swift2, nsurlsession

I'm hoping someone an help me figure out a problem that has me scratching my brain!  When I attempt this function using a `NSData(contentsOfUrl...` structure, this all works fine.  However, I am attempting to use a `NSURLSession` for use on an Apple Watch app, and keep hitting an error;

**...**

```
    class func fetchData() -> [Complication] {

        var task: NSURLSessionDataTask?

        let myURL = "http://www.myurl.com/sample.json"

        let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

        let conf = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        conf.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: conf)

        task = session.dataTaskWithURL(dataURL!) { (data, res, error) -> Void in
            if let e = error {
                print("dataTaskWithURL fail: \(e.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            var dataSet = [Complication]()

            do {

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                for item in json {
                    let name: String? = item["name"] as? String
                    let percent: Int? = item["percent"] as? Int
                    let timeFromNow: Int? = item["timeFromNow"] as? Int

                    let myData = Complication(
                        name: name!,
                        percent: percent!,
                        timeFromNow: timeFromNow!
                    )
                    dataSet.append(myData)
                }   
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return dataSet
//THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
    }
```

**...**

When attempting to return my `dataSet` array, I receive the error **Instance member 'dataSet' cannot be used on type 'Complication'**.  As mentioned, however, this does seem to work if I were to use a `NSData(contentsOfUrl...` instead of a `NSURLSession`, which is where I am stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data task is a closure that is executed asynchronously. Its return statements returns from the closure, not from the outer function.

Since the closure is executed asynchronously it makes no sense to return data from it: the return type is Void.

You should organize your code differently, e.g. using a completion handler.

Hint: search for "swift return closure" in SO. You will find plenty of questions similar to yours and a number of good answers and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, Mario!  I know your answer is correct, though I've been having some trouble figuring out how to implement a return in the `NSURLSession`, even with the examples I'm finding online.  I am going to keep searching and working on it, but any further hints would be most appreciated.  And again, thank you!

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct but ask a new question regarding the completion handler.  My searching on Stack Overflow, extensively, has not yielded a proper example of how to return an array of data to the function.